# Equivalent of Lua's pairs() for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lua, iteration

I need a common API to iterate Python objects as key/index and value pairs. Such that:

```
for k,v in pairs({"foo": "bar"}):
    print(k, v)
```

outputs "foo bar", and

```
for i,v in pairs(["foo", "bar"]):
    print(i, v)
```

outputs "0 foo" and "1 bar", as the Lua equivalent would (except corrected for 0-indexing vs 1-indexing).

Does such an API exist?

Comment: you need `{"foo": "bar"}.items()`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre doesn't work on lists or tuples.

Comment: There is no single function that behaves the way you describe. Use the `items` method for mappings and `enumerate` for list-like iterables.

Comment: @SoniEx2: Why do you *need* a "common API" for this? What are you doing where you don't know whether a type is a dictionary or a list? Python isn't Lua, and you shouldn't write Python code the way you would Lua code. One of the most important parts of learning a new programming language is to learn its *idioms*, the way code gets written in that language. Importing idioms from another language should only be done if you absolutely have to. This is not a "need"; it's personal preference.

Comment: @NicolBolas config files. Lua actually gets their semantics right.

Comment: Semantically, Lua tables are just hash tables, so why not just convert them to `dict`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can emulate the "pairs" function by testing the input type and use `items` in case of a dictionary, and `enumerate` in case of a list, tuple, or default to `enumerate` which will work on any iterable:

```
def pairs(o):
    if isinstance(o,dict):
        return o.items()
    else:
        return enumerate(o)


for k,v in pairs({"foo": "bar"}):
    print(k, v)
for i,v in pairs(["foo", "bar"]):
    print(i, v)
```

prints:

```
foo bar
0 foo
1 bar
```

Also: change to `return enumerate(o,1)` to make indices start at 1.

Comment: Instead of sniffing the type of `o`, I would just put `return o.items()` in a `try` block, and return `enumerate(o)` in the event of an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @chepner Handling exceptions is more expensive than an `if`-test. If the exceptions occur frequently an `if`-`else` statement is more appropriate.

Comment: Calling `pairs` in the first place (and detecting which idiom to use at runtime instead of simply writing type-aware code in the first place) is also expensive.

Comment: exception solution is faster when called with a dictionary type most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

For a `dict`, use the `items` method:

```
for k, v in {"foo": "bar"}.items():
    print(k, v)
```

There is no equivalent for lists. However, you may want to check the grouper recipe in the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

To convert the dict to an iterable that would work with `grouper`, use `itertools.chain.from_iterable({"a": 1, "b": 2}.items())`.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to iterate lists as value-pairs, but as (index,value) pairs (like in `enumerate`).

Comment: Then use `enumerate`. There's no reason why there should be a single function that does two unrelated things like `pairs` appears to do.